# navigator.getUserMedia not working on safari but working on other browsers

Tags: javascript

In my application one of my xhtml page is accessing camera, for that i have created a script, the script is below

```
function getCamera() {
    navigator.getMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia || // use the proper vendor prefix
           navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
           navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
           navigator.msGetUserMedia);
    navigator.getMedia({video: true}, function() {
      console.log("webcam is available ");
      document.getElementById('camera-image').style.display='';
      document.getElementById('no-image').style.display='none';
    }, function() {
      console.log("webcam is not available ");
      document.getElementById('camera-image').style.display='none';
      document.getElementById('no-image').style.display='';
    });
}
```

this script is working fine on chrome, firefox, opera but not working on safari.

can anyone help me in that?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia. deprecated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to MDN Docs, [navigator.getUserMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia) is deprecated, and not supported in Safari browser.
You can see the Compatibility table taken from the MDN Docs.
[image]

Instead, you can use the [navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) which has better support for different browser.
[image]

Try this code. Hope, this may help you

```
function getCamera() {

  if (!navigator.mediaDevices && !navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.userMedia = navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.getUserMedia
    if (!navigator.userMedia) {
      alert("Please Update or Use Different Browser");
      return
    }
    navigator.userMedia({
      video: true
    }, (stream) => showCam(stream), (err) => showErr(err))
    return
  }

  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      video: true
    })
    .then((stream) => showCam(stream))
    .catch((err) => showErr(err))

  function showCam(stream) {
    let video = document.querySelector("video");
    video.srcObject = stream;
  }

  function showErr(err) {
    let message = err.name === "NotFoundError" ? "Please Attach Camera" :
      err.name === "NotAllowedError" ? "Please Grant Permission to Access Camera" : err
    alert(message)
  }
}
```